# Reverse engineer xml schema needed for xmldp query from SSRS web service

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, visual-studio-2010

How can I build a correct xmldp query to the SSRS webservice in reporting services of visual studio?
I suspect the structure sent to web service is incorrect or types in web service are not synchronized -- so I suspect the web service is getting `0` or `null` from the reporting service.

this is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
- <wsdl:definitions name="TATEST" targetNamespace="http://namespace.softwareag.com/entirex/xml/mapping" xmlns:tns="http://namespace.softwareag.com/entirex/xml/mapping" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sn0="somenamespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
- <wsdl:types>
- <xsd:schema targetNamespace="somenamespace">
- <xsd:element name="TATESTResponse">
- <xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:sequence>
- <xsd:element name="_PAR1">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="1" />
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:element name="_PAR2">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="1" />
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:element name="TATEST">
- <xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:sequence>
- <xsd:element name="_PAR1">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="1" />
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:element name="_PAR2">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="1" />
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
……
```

and the is xmldp query from the ssrs

```
<Query>
<SoapAction>TATEST</SoapAction>
<Method Name="TATEST" Namespace="somenamespace">
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="_PAR1">
<DefaultValue>2</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="_PAR2">
<DefaultValue>1</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespace="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Comment: Can you please post the xmldp you have tried and any error messages that are being returned?

Comment: Hi,i didnt get any error data but i understood from the dba, no parameter values were supplied for the web service:

Comment: Probably better to add those details to the question rather than use comments.  You should be able to edit your own question at any time.

Comment: What is this `TATEST` method that you are expecting to find on the SSRS WebService?

Comment: the SSRS is not the web service.from the SSRS i'm using web service as a datasource and in the xmldp query(query designer) i'm sending parameters and trying to retrieve data(dataset)